# Не применяются .css стили к html (Python3, FLASK)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Разрабатываю Python приложение(сайт) используя Flask.

Во flask по стандарту тег `<style>` в html не читается, поэтому flask выведет страницу без стилей.
Чтобы страница отображалась со стилями - нужно показать библиотеке где они находятся

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{url_for('static',filename='css/commons.css') }}" />`

Но у меня стили находятся в самом HTML файле под тегом `<style>`.

Могу ли я объявить стили не перенося их в файл `.css` из моего html? Или всё-таки придется перенести стили в `.css`?

PS: напомню - используется библиотека Flask

Comment: `Во flask по стандарту тег <style> в html не читается` фигня какая-то, причем тут flask и html с css? flask вернет страницу html браузеру и тот уже будет читать ее на этом роль flask закончится

Answer (score 0):

Тег `<style>` в HTML работает только для данного документа HTML и наследовать стили из других не получится, если вы об этом.

К примеру стили в base.html

```html
<style>
    body {
        background: #000
    }
</style>
```

Не будут применены к другим страницам

Comment: нет, я про то, что во flask по стандарту тег style в html не читается, поэтому flask выведет страницу без стилей. Чтобы страница отображалась со стилями - нужно показать библиотеке где они находятся



<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='css/commons.css') }}" />
 


Но у меня стили находятся в самом HTML файле под тегом <style>

Comment: Я понял. Вот что предлагают из-за рубежа:

<link ... href="{{ url_for('static', filename='stylesheets/style.css') }}" />

Ссылка на фулл: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772884/css-problems-with-flask-web-app

Comment: @АлександрКудинов, там еще предлагают перезапустить браузер и скорее всего заодно кэш почистить: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59332284/5909792